# Mount git branches in a container

Tags: git, docker

I have a git repository with 2 distinct branches, for instance `master` and `foo`:

```
mkdir test && cd test
git init
echo master > master
git add . && git commit -m "init master"
git checkout -b foo
rm master
echo foo > foo
git add . && git commit -m "init foo"
```

Now I want to mount `master` and `foo` in a container as separated volumes, in order to have this architecture in my container:

```
.
├── foo
│   └── foo
└── master
    └── master
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You'd need two clones, one with `master` checked out and one with `foo` checked out. It might make more sense to just have one clone inside the VM and use it like a normal git clone.

Comment: Yes why not? Checkout the project 2 times and checkout the branch you want.

Comment: several clones works, but it duplicates data...

Comment: Oh, you mean local clones, I did not know we can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two [git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). Worktrees allow you to have more than one branch checked out at different paths.

```
$ git status
On branch master
…
$ git worktree add ../develop
Preparing ../develop (identifier develop)
HEAD is now at fbbbc04 netcat6 for gnks
$ git -C ../develop status
On branch develop
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then mount those directories in your container.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine.

Comment: How do I update my worktree? ie, from branch master: `touch blah && git add . && git commit -m "blah" && ls ../develop` doesn't show the new file `blah`. Do I need to remove the worktree and add it again each time I want to update it?

Comment: Each worktree is on a different branch. If you add a file to master, it doesn't put it in the develop branch until you bring that commit into develop by doing a merge, rebase or cherry-pick.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need two clones, one with `master` checked out and one with `foo` checked out. They can be shallow clones to save space.

```
git clone file:///full/path/to/the/repo --depth 1 --branch master master
git clone file:///full/path/to/the/repo --depth 1 --branch foo foo
```

It might make more sense to just have one clone inside the VM and use it like a normal git clone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can mount git branches as-is.
However, if Schern answer isn't enough (you may want to have a common repository and two working directories) I'd recommand looking into this:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

That way, both directories will share the same .git directory (one will be an instruction for git to look in the other)